# Environment for text labeling and explanation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for a tex environment which allows me to label text like this: [image]
Since the word 'label' is already occupied I don't know how to google for a solution. Does anyone have an idea? Maybe there is a tikz solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can define a simple macro for this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\newcommand{\yourcmd}[3]{%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,red] (a) {#1};
        \draw[red] (a.south west)--(a.south east);
        \coordinate (a1) at (a.south);
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,right=0pt of a] (b) {#2};
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,right=0pt of b,green!50!black] (c) {#3};
        \draw[green!50!black] (c.south west)--(c.south east);
        \coordinate (c1) at (c.south);
        \draw[red] ($(a1)+(-110:0.1)$)--($(a1)+(-110:1)$) node[fill=white,font=\tiny\sffamily,inner sep=2pt] {Some text};
        \draw[green!50!black] ($(c1)+(-70:0.1)$)--($(c1)+(-70:1)$) node[fill=white,font=\tiny\sffamily,inner sep=2pt] {Hello world};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\yourcmd{12}{34567}{8910}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This looks great so far. But is also a more generic solution possible? I think of n labeled parts to which I can pass individual colors and description texts? Probably, my question wasn't formulated clear enough...

Comment: @lukasl1991 In fact, I don't think you really need a macro. It is just a centered Ti*k*Z picture, and looking at my code I think you can do for yourself.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. Thanks!